# How to do SELECT CONVERT(bigint,some_field) in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, casting

I have a SQL query that looks like

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, MY_TABLE_FIELD)
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE [CONDITIONS]
```

I need to cast the string `MY_TABLE_FIELD` to a long value field in Linq.

I've tried with `long.tryParse`, `(long)MY_TABLE_FIELD`, and `Convert.ToInt64(MY_TABLE_FIELD)` inside the select clause in the Linq expression.

I have read about methods that converts value, but i get error. And I don't want to use lambda expressions.

What can I do?

Comment: Please show your code and let us know what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your values are actually convertible to `long`s, you should be able to do this:

```
from context.SOME_TABLE
where ...
select Convert.ToInt64(row.MY_TABLE_FIELD)
```

If the values are not convertible to `long`s, you might want to consider selecting out the string from the database, and then post-processing the values based on more complex business logic.

(If this doesn't work, provide the error message that you're getting, and more details on your  database, etc.)

Comment: I have a answer, but i am new here and cannot answer my own questions after 8 hours

Answer (score 0):

Thanks StriplingWarrior for your answer.

I´ve found a solutions few minutes after i posted the question.

Here I share it.

LINQ

```
var MyList = (from ta in model.Table
              select new MyClass
              {
                   StringFieldID = ta.StringFieldID,
                   OtherField = ta.OtherField
              }).ToList();
```

And the work i did it on the class MyClass Code

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _StringFieldID;
    public long LongFieldID { set; get; }


    public string OtherField{set;get;}
    public string StringFieldID{
        set
        {
            _StringFieldID= value;
            LongFieldID= long.Parse(_StringFieldID);
        }
        get
        {
            return _StringFieldID;
        }
    }
}
```

So, every time the Linq Query sets a value for StringFieldID is the class who makes the casting.